# I'm using ftools in a ruby 1.8 application, how can I make this compatible with ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, file

What is the best way to make code using ftools also compatible with 1.9?

Comment: Can you explain what does not work under 1.9?

Comment: My solution to ftools in ruby 1.9 was just remove the require line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FileUtils](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/fileutils/1.9.2/frames). The APIs aren't totally compatible, but they're close, and FileUtils is also available for pre 1.9.

I'd update all code using ftools to use FileUtils, then iron out any discrepancies. It'll be worth it, FileUtils is here to stay.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. @Phrogz, I was using File.copy, it now occurs to me I should have been using FileUtils all along.